# How are the electronics and chips inside the microwave protected from the microwave radiation/energy?

Tags: design, consumer-electronics, thermal-insulation, radiation

Let's say I put in an endoscope like camera with the lens at the inside edge of the box and the wire behind metal sheet. Here's a mockup:

[image: poorly made diagram]

Could use microwave reflecting or absorbing wrap to wrap the body/wire of the camera.

Would an endoscope like camera be safe from microwave radiation/energy behind the inside microwave box?

Comment: The question asked in the title does not match what you ask in the body of the question. Edit it to be clear what you ask.

Comment: The microwaves internal walls reflect rather than absorb the energy. Your lens will not.

Comment: @JonathanRswift think theres anyway to shield the lens? I'm think it might be possible behind the little holes.

Comment: @solarmike okay, will reword and post

Comment: If you have to come to this site to ask such a question, that means you are not qualified to be messing around with microwave ovens. They are DANGEROUS !

Comment: @William Hird: Not to mention you will definitely void the warranty  ;-)     tigertiger: Seriously, though, various makes and models are constructed differently. It would therefore be better to contact the manufacturer. Their technical/development teams probably have experience with inserting various instruments into prototypes for testing, so will be better able to advise you.

Answer (score 0):

The microwave will create a set of standing waves in the 'box'. These waves are formed from the left (notice the mica plate, which appears off-white and acts as a waveguide cover) and reflect back from the right metal panel. The wavelength of these waves is approximately 12.8cm, because microwave radiation inside microwave ovens (and the resonant frequency of water molecules) is 2.45GHz. This means that 'nodes' of the standing wave are 6.4cm apart. Since the electric field is 0 at these nodes, there is no heating. Therefore, your food must turn on a plate to be heated uniformly!

If you could find a way to place your camera at one of these nodes, it would be completely unaffected. Finding a node in the middle of the oven isn't going to be easy. There are crude methods, like putting chocolate in the oven and looking to see where melting occurs (after the turntable has been removed). However, the electric field will be 0 at both of the left and right sides of the oven. Place your camera there, and it should be OK too.

Drilling holes and modifying microwave ovens isn't recommended, though. They have magnetrons operating at several thousand volts and are a death trap for the untrained/unsure. Although microwave radiation is non-ionising, it can be pumped out of a microwave oven at a level of power that could be detrimental to your health. A modified microwave oven should not be regularly used, because it's likely it will be leaking EM radiation.

Your safest option, in my opinion, is to video or film from behind the window. It appears that many other people film behind a microwave by using a very wide aperture lens which allows the 'mesh' of the microwave's door to appear invisible. You could modify the microwave door (somewhat safely) by drilling an opening into the glass of 1cm or so---again, this is risky.

Comment: The mica plate does not act as a waveguide, it merely prevents food and debris from getting into the waveguide. Mica is used because it can withstand serious heat and is transparent to microwaves.

Comment: this a great answer. I've been holding back b/c I am untrained. The final intent is to have it be part of a commercial shipped microwave, a built in feature you could say. the customer would never need ot see it other than to wipe it clean with the rest of the microwave